# Spring data mongodb - MappedResults returns blank list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongodb query is:

```
db.getCollection('country2').aggregate([{"$lookup":{"from":"state2","localFiel
        d":"_id","foreignField":"countryId","as":"state2"}}]).pretty()
```

returns this result :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b520333a04107677b5ce1"),
        "countryName" : "India",
        "state2" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b515b33a04107677b5cdb"),
                        "stateName" : "UP",
                        "countryId" : ObjectId("5b2b520333a04107677b5ce1")
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b516033a04107677b5cdc"),
                        "stateName" : "MP",
                        "countryId" : ObjectId("5b2b520333a04107677b5ce1")
                }
        ]
}
```

Aggregation query returns blank MappedResults though raw results contain the expected results.
State2 is my java pojo.

```
public List<BasicDBObject> getAllData() {
        LookupOperation lookUpOprn = LookupOperation.newLookup()
                .from("state2")
                .localField("_id")
                .foreignField("countryId")
                .as("state2");

        org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOptions options = Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().cursor(new BasicDBObject()).build(); 
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookUpOprn).withOptions(options);

        List<BasicDBObject> list =  mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "country2", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
        return list;
    }
```

Can you please help.